# Assistance needed for regex python

Tags: python, regex

i have a file similar to that shown below- is it possible to perform a regex expression

```
text1  769,230,123
text2  70
text3  213,445
text4  24,356
text5  1,2,4
```

to give output as shown here?

```
['769','230','123']
['70']
['213','445']
```

My current code is as follows:

```
with open(filename,'r') as output:
    for line in output:
        a = line
        a = a.strip()
        #regex.compile here
        print regex.findall(a)
```

Any help or direction would be greatly useful to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will extract the comma separated numbers from the line, and then we can apply `split(',')` in order to extract the numbers:

```
import re
line = "text1  769,230,123"
mat = re.match(r'.*? ([\d+,]+).*', line)
nums = mat.group(1).split(',')
for num in nums:
    print num
```

**OUTPUT**

```
769
230
123
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could just findall number sequences:

```
regex = re.compile("[ ,]([0-9]+)")
```

Comment: -1 using this regex to search the line will also return the `1` from `text1`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b\d+\b')
>>> with open(filename, 'r') as output:
...     for line in output:
...         matches = regex.findall(line)
...         for m in matches:
...             print m
```

Output

```
769
230
123
70
213
445
24
356
1
2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this. Just `line.split(',')`.

Comment: -1 If we'll take your suggestion, the first line will return "text1  769" as the first value of the split.

Comment: @alfasin Could just split twice? `x.split(',') for x in line.split(' ')`. I find it easier to comprehend.

Comment: @VivekRai counting on the number of spaces and on the position of each element from the split in the resulted list seems very unsafe IMHO.

Comment: Sure. Just in the the OP wished to try out other alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have 2 spaces between `text#` and your comma separated values. Here's a simple way to extract the separated values into arrays

```
list = []
with open(filename,'r') as output:
    for line in output:
        line = line.strip('  ')
        list.append(line[1].strip(','))
```

This will produce a nested list

```
print list[0] #['769','230','123']
print list[1] #['70']
print list[2] #['213','445']
```